# Use 0 or not 0 as boolean in lua[jit]

Tags: lua, numbers, boolean, ffi, luajit

I have a C function that returns 0 or non zero as a boolean to tell the user if all went right.

```
/* Returns non-zero on success, 0 on failure. */
int do_something(void) { 
   int success = NON_ZERO; 
   ...
   if (error) {
       success = 0;
   }
   ...
  return success;
}
```

In C, I will use this function as such

```
if (do_something()) {
    proceed();
}
```

I use the luajit ffi to expose this function to lua

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
int do_something(void);
]]
do_something = ffi.C.do_something
```

Problem is, lua doesn't want to use the integer return value as a boolean true/false.

```
if (do_something()) then
   -- do_something() always evaluates to true no matter the return value
end
-- I have to do
if (do_something() ~= 0) then
   -- only executed if return value is non-zero
end
```

How do I get lua to evalute the return value of do_something() such that I don't have to check for non-zero manually?

Also, I cannot create a wrapper around do_something() such as

```
do_something = function() ffi.C.do_something() ~= 0 end
```

because the do_something ffi binding is automatically generated and doesn't know wether an integer return value is used as a boolean or an actual integer.

Comment: what's wrong with `do_something() ~= 0`?   if your "wrapper" would return a value that would also look ok to me.

Comment: Why not to use  `ffi.cdef[[ bool do_something(void); ]]`. Any number in lua *is* allways true and ffi has type bool exactly for such cases as yours.

Comment: @Piglet It's just annoying to type and ugly.

Comment: @Darius That may be what I'm looking for, thank you. I thought that wouldn't work since bool is just a typedef for int.

Comment: why could you not create a wrapper? your missing a `return` in the example in your question `do_something = function() return ffi.C.do_something() ~= 0 end`

Comment: `bool` is _not_ a typedef for int. Using it on a function that actually returns `int` will break things.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo `bool` return value if it is not pointer can't break anything as internaly it uses register size which is normaly the same size as int. `bool` is C99/C++ type in *compiler* and it has no real `true` value, only `false` value. In decompiled code (assembler) you will see no difference between `int myFunc() {return 0;}` and `bool myFunc() {return false;}`. So it is safe to use `bool` instead of `int` in ffi.